# Hidden ponies deserve autocompletion love too

Tags: bug, status-completed, autocomplete

Fairly minor bug, but the username autocomplete doesn't rebuild its list of users immediately after hidden comments are loaded from the server, allowing for situations like the following where late-comers to the comment thread are excluded:

[image: OMG, ponies?]

Causing the textarea to refocus fixes things, since it has the full list of comments to work with at that point. However, since the textarea is auto-focused after you click the link to load additional comments, it's not too hard to end up in a situation where you don't have all of the expected names displayed.

Ideally, the autocomplete list would be forced to update once the comments were done loading.

Comment: +1 for a great title

Comment: @TheUnhandledException I almost edited it so it would actually be discoverable, but I figured the odds of a duplicate are low

Comment: I so would have rolled that back @Michael ;-)

Comment: Also another +1 for cropping this in the middle of Beckers' name. I'm sure she loves that ;-)

Comment: @KebeccaCnerhott, The Unhandled Exception is right, Tim Stone is not treating you with respect.

Comment: (@TheUnhandledException, see above comment)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[image: the problem's solution, in graphical form]

Comment: In Future `status-completed` will only be accepted if accompanied with a similar image. This is to be the new standard!

Comment: The awesomeity of this answer leaves me no choice but to declare you winner of Meta.